Why is my recaptcha key type is invaalid?
Im trying to follow this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@alejandroleonnavarro.david/php-how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-v2-7e0be9a0c126
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

of course my "site key" is good. I created it as "testing key", Im on localhost, and "domain verification" is disabled. Why isnt it working?
